# Grails war deployment on Tomcat asking for hsql driver instead of mysql

Tags: mysql, tomcat, grails, deployment, hsqldb

I have a grails app that I am trying to deploy onto Tomcat. I used to develop on hsql and wanted to use mysql for production. But when I build the war by running

```
grails prod war demo.war
```

and deploy the created war in the tomcat/webapps directory, I get the following error

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive demo.war
2011-11-29 17:30:03,193 [Thread-2] INFO  cfg.Environment  - Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
2011-11-29 17:30:03,224 [Thread-2] INFO  cfg.Environment  - hibernate.properties not found
2011-11-29 17:30:03,240 [Thread-2] INFO  cfg.Environment  - Bytecode provider name : javassist
2011-11-29 17:30:03,251 [Thread-2] INFO  cfg.Environment  - using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
2011-11-29 17:31:25,451 [Thread-2] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demoapp?autoreconnect=true'
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

What's puzzling is that I have removed the hsql dependency completely from the Datasource.groovy file. Here is how my Datasource.groovy looks now.

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driver.name = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"   
    username = "root"
    password = "root"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            pooled = true
            driver.name = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demoapp_dev?autoreconnect=true"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driver.name = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demoapp_test?autoreconnect=true"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            pooled = true
            driver.name = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demoapp?autoreconnect=true"
            username = "root"
            password = ""
        }
    }
}
```

How do I get around this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: schmolly159 is correct - it's `driverClassName` not `driver.name`. Since `driverClassName` isn't set Grails defaults to the HSQLDB driver

Comment: Oh wow! I just noticed that Burt Beckwith commented on this. +1 to the grails community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `driverClassName` instead of `driver.name` to define your `DataSource` driver.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you <s>don't have the MySQL driver in your class path</s> don't have the `driverClassName`, as per schmolly159's answer.

<s>Make sure `mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx.jar` is in your `lib` directory or declare it as a dependency in `BuildConfig.groovy`</s>.

Comment: I already have the mysql-connector-java-5.1.13.jar and mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar as a dependency and present in the webapps/demo/WEB-INF/lib folder. Is there any other reason this could be happening?

Comment: Is the mysql connector jar file part of the `Bundle-ClassPath` property in your warfile's `MANIFEST.MF`?  It should be automatically set by grails when you do a `grails war`.

Comment: He'd get a `ClassNotFoundEXception` if the jar wasn't listed as a dependency or in the lib dir, not the behavior he's seeing

Comment: Yes, the mysql connector file is listed as part of BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: Your answer was part correct. I was missing the mysql dependency on the grails project but it was being satisfied by another project's libs. So technically both the answers were right, but I cannot split the correct answer in two :) Thanks!